# Inserting an element at a specific (initally empyt) path

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I want to add an element to an xml-file at a specific path whose subnodes do not exist in the initial *example.xml* file. When adding the element, I want to create all the necessary child nodes "on the fly" and not one at a time.

I don't know the correct way to do it, the following code-snipped is just an example for illustration purposes. Maybe it is possible using different methods from etree.

My example:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
path = etree.Element('/leadSinger/names/firstName')
etree.Element(path, "Freddie")

tree.write('example.xml')
```

The initial *example.xml* file:

```
<interpret>
    <name>Queen</name>
<interpret>
```

The *example.xml* file after the element was created, inserted and written:

```
<interpret>
    <name>Queen</name>
    <leadSinger>
        <names>
            <firstName>Freddie</firstName>
        </names>
    </leadSinger>
</interpret>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way:

```
lead = """<leadSinger>
        <names>
            <firstName>Freddie</firstName>
        </names>
    </leadSinger>    
    """

elem = etree.fromstring(lead)
destination = root.xpath('//interpret/name')[0]

destination.addnext(elem)

print(etree.tostring(root, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

Which should get you the expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much! The last question I have is how I convert a string path like '/leadSinger/names/firstName' to the necessary syntax of the lead variable.

Comment: @PhilE: you should post a new question about that. Ask one question at a time.